# How can I read element style with transition in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have an element that I change width within component. This element has CSS property transition for width. I would like to call a function whenever that element width reaches '100%'. I know I can get the width value with this code `this._expBar.nativeElement.style.width`. The problem is that this will return me width that I have set not the current one. Can I read the current state of CSS property that takes in consideration the transition? Or at least can I read if there is any transition happening right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`transition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event) events

1. `transitionrun` when the transition effect starts even if there is a delay.
2. `transitionstart` executes after delay.
3. `transitioncancel` executes when the transition is canceled.
4. `transitionend` executes when the transition is ended.

For example

```js
const message = document.querySelector('.message');
const el = document.querySelector('.transition');

el.addEventListener('transitionrun', () => {
  message.textContent = 'transitionrun fired';
});

el.addEventListener('transitionstart', () => {
  message.textContent = 'transitionstart fired';
});

el.addEventListener('transitioncancel', () => {
  message.textContent = 'transitioncancel fired';
});

el.addEventListener('transitionend', () => {
  message.textContent = 'transitionend fired';
});
```

```css
.transition {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1);
  transition-property: transform, background;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.transition:hover {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="transition">Hover over me</div>
<div class="message"></div>
```